# How to target the svg-element created by a Lottie animation?

Tags: javascript, html, css, target, lottie

I'm trying to target the svg-element that's created by my lottie-animation with CSS to give it some border-radius. Being rather unexperienced with JavaScript and CSS, I couldn't figure out how to do it.

I've already tried targeting the svg-element as a child of the lottie-player-element by using:

```
lottie-player svg {
border-radius: 9px;
}
```

I assume this doesn't work, because the svg isn't present in the original HTML code and only added later through JavaScript. Is that correct?

Do you have any ideas how to give this animation rounded corners, ideally through CSS?

Here's a codepen to play around with: https://codepen.io/Kartenhouse/pen/JjpmXem

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Unfortunately, no there is no way to target the generated SVG with css with lottie. You would need to adjust the svg/animation how you would like, and generate a new lottie `.json` file

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a parent div and do all CSS properties there instead to lottie player.
Like what I have done. [Codepen for reference](https://codepen.io/Ajai-S-S/pen/BaYqzWW)

**HTML :** Parented the lottie player

```
<div id="lottie">
  <lottie-player src="https://assets5.lottiefiles.com/datafiles/zc3XRzudyWE36ZBJr7PIkkqq0PFIrIBgp4ojqShI/newAnimation.json" speed="1" loop autoplay>
  </lottie-player>
</div>
```

**CSS :** Added CSS to parent div instead of HTML.

```
#lottie {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  border-radius: 12px;
  z-index: 12;
  background-color: #000000;
}
```

The final output looks like this

[image]

Note: If you need lottie controls then you need to write your own logic for player to start and stop animation.

Comment: Thanks a lot for sharing your approach! It certainly works for this specific animation, but it has an issue: The animation itself still expands beyond the borders of the div if given a chance. 
You can see what I mean if you write `border-radius: 100%`, and watch the blue circle on the top-left. It goes beyond the borders.

Comment: ok ok got it. In that case what you need to do is you need to set child entity little bit smaller than parent entity using width ,height  in CSS to inner lottie player